# Invert a list without the last element in Racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to write a Racket function with tail recursion, it should return the inverted list but the last element should remain in the last position.

That is, I need to get from the example:

```
(reversar-lista '(1 2 3 4))
>(3 2 1 4)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (reversar-lista lista)
(define (reversa-aux lista aux)
  (if (null? lista) aux
      (reversa-aux (cdr lista) (reverse (cons (car lista) aux)))
  )
 )
  (reversa-aux lista '())
 )
```

I get the following output:

```
(3 1 2 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to solve this question using only built-in procedures, there's no need to implement explicit looping logic:

```
(define (reversar-lista lista)
  (if (null? lista)
      '()
      (append (reverse (drop-right lista 1))
              (take-right lista 1))))
```

Of course, it's also possible to write a solution by hand - but you have to be careful with the edge cases, in particular watch out for the empty list case.

The main problems with your solution are that you must stop the recursion *before* the last element, and that you must not `reverse` the result at every iteration, the list is being built in reverse anyway. This is what I mean:

```
(define (reversar-lista lista)
  (define (reversa-aux lista aux)
    (if (null? (cdr lista))
        (append aux (list (car lista)))
        (reversa-aux (cdr lista) (cons (car lista) aux))))
  (if (null? lista)
      '()
      (reversa-aux lista '())))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(reversar-lista '())
=> '()
(reversar-lista '(1))
=> '(1)
(reversar-lista '(1 2))
=> '(1 2)
(reversar-lista '(1 2 3))
=> '(2 1 3)
(reversar-lista '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(3 2 1 4)
```